# When I use gimp cage transform but it crashes

Tags: gimp

[image]

How can I fix this problem of gimp crashing?

Comment: Have you tried removing and reinstalling it ?

Comment: george it didn't :(

Comment: Could you please run `gimp` in a terminal, try the transformation, and [edit] your question to include the *full, verbatim* output of it? To achieve that two you can either 1) select, copy & paste the dialogue text or terminal content or 2) [save the program output to a file](//askubuntu.com/q/420981/175814) and use that. Longer listings (≥100 lines) should be uploaded to a [pastie service](https://paste.ubuntu.com/) and linked to in the question. Thanks.

Comment: rup' paketinden 'rstat-client' komutu (universe)
runq' paketinden 'exim4-daemon-light' komutu (main)
runq' paketinden 'exim4-daemon-heavy' komutu (main)
runq' paketinden 'sendmail-bin' komutu (universe)
grun' paketinden 'grun' komutu (universe)
qrun' paketinden 'torque-client' komutu (universe)
qrun' paketinden 'torque-client-x11' komutu (universe)
'rn' paketinden 'trn4' komutu (multiverse)
'rn' paketinden 'trn' komutu (multiverse)
'zrun' paketinden 'moreutils' komutu (universe)
'srun' paketinden 'slurm-client' komutu (universe)
'runc' paketinden 'runc' komutu (universe)

Answer (score 5):

This is a known bug in Ubuntu's GIMP package, and there does not appear to be an easy way to solve it until the bug has been fixed. They've confirmed the bug and given it High importance, so there's hope!

https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/gimp/+bug/1614593

The cause appears to be:

> ...Debian and/or Ubuntu decided to make their GIMP 2.8
>   packages depend on gegl-0.3 instead of gegl-0.2 came as a surprise to
>   some of the GIMP developers.

The bug is confirmed for the latest stable release of GIMP 2.8.20 on Ubuntu 16.04.2 LTS (as of this post)

If you can figure out how to apply them, there is a patch available in the bug report linked to above.

Comment: A workaround is remove and install it [with PPA](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/gimp/+bug/1614593/comments/22) or [just `sudo snap install gimp`](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/gimp/+bug/1614593/comments/25). This last version give now v2.10, by default with [dark theme](https://www.gimp.org/release-notes/gimp-2.10.html) ([a little bit odd in my case](https://i.imgur.com/0nm5p6m.png)). If you don't like it [just `snap remove gimp`](https://itsfoss.com/use-snap-packages-ubuntu-16-04/).

Answer (score 1):

Not a solution for your problem but that tool works ok if you use the "snapped" gimp in https://snapcraft.io/gimp

Snap is a packaging tool that allows apps to be self-contained, this leverages any dependencies and apps behave something like the MacOs apps.

To install snap

```
sudo apt install snapd
```

To install snapped gimp

```
sudo snap install gimp
```

To use snapped gimp

```
snap run gimp
```